# Implementing Template Method Design Pattern in RESTful services Java

Tags: java, rest, design-patterns

Anyone tried implementing Template Method Design pattern in REST? I am trying to separate common functions across the endpoints into a template method, so the framework is handling some of these. I could not figure out a way to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at RESTCommand.java from [a blog entry discussing Android RESTful pattern](http://android-restful-pattern.blogspot.ca/p/the-sync-in-action.html).

I'm pretty sure `execute()` is a template method (although not the greatest example since it's only calling a single abstract method that's overridden in subclasses). Note that this is likely also the Command pattern.

[image: RESTCommand architecture with template method]

Comment: My question is more around how to implement the pattern on a RESTService. Let's say, URI is /restservice/restmethod. Request gets to RESTMethod directly, I am looking for options to execute template method..same as above prior to invoking Rest Service.REST Method.

Comment: Patterns are tools to solve a problem. I'm not sure I understand where template method's problem fits into REST.

Comment: For example, Authentication and Session (just for example) Validation, these are common across all the use cases, so these can go into framework components rather than each and every REST method checking for those. By using template method, I can push those responsibilities to the template method which executes prior to calling REST Method..One way I was thinking to do it by implementing Servlet Filter..I rather prefer using a design patter if possible...

Comment: Template method is a pattern that assumes an order to polymorphic methods, which is a sort of algorithm. I think trying to use REST in this way is like a kind of application logic that would be in the presentation layer. I'm not sure that's consistent with REST architecture.